# .load() JQuery from another file using onclick()

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, jquery-load

I want a page to show a gallery of only one city at a time. I have a loadGallery() which I believed would insert a div class containing a specific city's images into the thumbnail div when clicked. Here is an example of how I call my function:

```
<div class="gallerynames">
    <div class="NYC">
        <a href="" onclick="loadGallery('NYC')">NYC Gallery</a>
    </div>
    <div class="LA">
        <a href="" onclick="loadGallery('LA')">LA Gallery</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="thumbnails"></div>
```

I placed my function at the end of the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadGallery(gallery) {
        switch (gallery) {
            case 'NYC':
                $("#thumbnails" ).load( "Galleries.html #NYC" );
                break;
            case 'LA':
                $("#thumbnails" ).load( "Galleries.html #LA" );
                break;
        }
    } 
</script>
```

My function doesn't seem to be loading the galleries from Galleries.html. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try inspecting developer console in your browser with F12

Comment: Do you have any js error? Or can you confirm your Galleries.html file be loaded with your script?